# Неверно определяется ширина элемента при подключении стилей программно

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно определить ширину вложенного элемента. При подключении стилей через js ширина определяется некоректно.

```js
function load_style() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    if (window_width > window_height) {
        $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style.css'>"));
    } else {
        $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style_mobile.css'>"));
    }
    var text_page_1_width = $("#main").find(".page_1").find(".el1").width();
    alert(text_page_1_width);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    load_style();
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info_panel {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #565656;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: right .325s linear;
    -moz-transition: right .325s linear;
    -ms-transition: right .325s linear;
    -o-transition: right .325s linear;
    transition: right .325s linear;
}

.i {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    font-size: 20vw;
    color: #434343;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #000, 0 1px 0 #444;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.el1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.5vw;
    top: 2.75vh;
    width: 500px;
    color: #565656;
    border: .4vw solid #565656;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

.el1:hover {
    background-color: #565656;
    color: white;
}

#show_info_panel {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: .1vw;
}

.el2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.325s linear;
    -moz-transition: right 0.325s linear;
    -ms-transition: right 0.325s linear;
    -o-transition: right 0.325s linear;
    transition: right 0.325s linear;
}

.slide_panel {
    right: 0;
}

.slide_content {
    right: 8.5vw;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'PT Serif Caption', serif;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    width: 500px;
}

svg {
    shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    clip-rule: evenodd;
}

svg.el3 {
    width: 7vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50vw;
    bottom: 5vh;
}

svg.el3:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

svg.el3 .str0 {
    stroke: #585656;
    stroke-width: 250;
}

svg.el3 .fil0 {
    fill: #565656;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

svg.el3 .fil1 {
    fill: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

svg.el3:hover .fil0 {
    fill: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

svg.el3:hover .fil1 {
    fill: #565656;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

#main .page_1 .el2 {
    top: 15vh;
}

#main .page_1 .el2 .text {
    width: 70vw;
}

#main .page_2 .el2 {
    top: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="main">
    <span id="preloader" style="display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;">
    </span>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section page_1">
            <div class="info_panel">
                <span class="i">i</span>
            </div>
            <div class="el1">
                <span id="show_info_panel">i</span>
            </div>
            <div class="el2">
                <span class="text">
                    Aleshkalavrushka.ml – только не надо путать подлинный продукт с тем, что продается в магазинах. Не смотри долго на Aleshkalavrushka.ml, а не то Aleshkalavrushka.ml взглянет на тебя. Вообще, думаю, что Aleshkalavrushka.ml – это аллегория. Вспоминаются стихи: «Идем по небесному телу Земля из точки рождения «А» в точку «Aleshkalavrushka.ml». *** Блуждаем по свету во тьме, пока нас не сцапает Aleshkalavrushka.ml. *** Хоть кажется, что это небыль, но по Земле ведет нас Aleshkalavrushka.ml». «Aleshkalavrushka.ml – не тот, кто в застолье крут, И когда за здоровье пьют, Aleshkalavrushka.ml не станет тебе кричать: «Пей до дна!», Aleshkalavrushka.ml почувствует, что тебе стало холодно на Земле, И согреет своим теплом без вина»... Тот, кто действительно имеет Aleshkalavrushka.ml, не боится признать своих ошибок. Где тебя рады видеть всегда? Там, где Aleshkalavrushka.ml. Мы всегда ждем Aleshkalavrushka.ml, и, в глубине души, надеемся, что с каждым разом Aleshkalavrushka.ml будет все лучше и лучше. Не бойтесь признаться в этом. Японские инженеры решили, что самой страшной болезнью будущего будет одиночество. Поэтому они встроили Aleshkalavrushka.ml в приборную доску нового автомобиля. Aleshkalavrushka.ml будет распознавать гримасы водителя и рассказывать ему анекдоты, чтобы поднять настроение. Aleshkalavrushka.ml становится не только повседневностью, но и принимается обществом и даже поощряется. А вот «Lm akhsurvalakhsela» – это Aleshkalavrushka.ml наоборот.
                </span>
            </div>
            <svg version=" 1.1 " class="el3 " viewBox="0 0 4335 4335 ">
                <ellipse class="fil0 str0 " cx="2167 " cy="2167 " rx="2000 " ry="2000 " />
                <path class="fil1" d="M2207 2445l1067 -747c64,-45 137,9 163,118l9 41c26,110 -5,236 -68,280l-1040 729c-16,13 -72,39 -126,41 -55,2 -108,-21 -125,-34l-1047 -762c-63,-46 -93,-172 -67,-281l10 -41c27,-109 101,-161 164,-115l1060 771z " />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="section page_2">
            <div class="el2">
                <p class="text">
                    Глянь - из дядиной гладильни,
                    <br> вожделенный и взрывной,
                    <br> выбегает эпилептик
                    <br> с синтетической серьгой!
                    <br>
                    <br> Королество заорало,
                    <br> замусолилась слеза,
                    <br> дуло злобно заскользило,
                    <br> и растрогалась хамса...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Не знаю как исправить эту ошибку. Ошибка где-то в подключении стилей (там, где у меня в js это делается программно). Тут задал css всё работает. У себя тоже задал всё работает. а если не задавать стиль и подключать через js, то в ie всё норм, а в хроме нет. Всё время выдаёт ширину 1333. Что у меня не так? [Пример. (Определяется ширина элемента el1 с заданным значением 500px)](http://aleshkalavrushka.ml/)

Answer (score 1):

Фишка в том, что вы используете [блочные элементы](http://htmlbook.ru/content/blochnye-elementy), поэтому без явного указания ширины, она всегда будет 100%.
Используйте не блочные...
В примере показано, что ширина всех блочных элементов равна ширине документа.
Не блочного (`span`) равна реальной ширине.

```js
out = '';
$('.el').each(function(i, v) {
  out += i + '-' + ($(v).find('p').width() | $(v).find('h1').width() | $(v).width()) + '<br>';
})
out += '4-' + $('.el:last>span').width();
$('.out').html(out)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="page_1">
    <div class="el">
      My text is a very smaller text.
    </div>
    <div class="el">
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</p>
    </div>
    <div class="el">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="el">
      <span> My text is a very longer text. Please, help me. :)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="out">
```

Comment: А как мне получить ширину блочного элемента?

Comment: А понял что вы имели ввиду. Но я, как я уже писал, указывал ширину и     он почему возвращает всю ширину документа. Или надо указывать для каждого элемента ширину? Могу пример скинуть

Comment: Скидывай, посмотрим

Comment: Хрен знает. Сейчас просто перекопировал свой html и css. JS оставил как был. (не который у меня в проекте).  Всё заработало. Видимо в моём коде (который у меня в проекте) что-то мешает выполнению. (хотя я пробовал перестраивать с нуля. Всё равно неполучалось). Завтро отпишусь.

Comment: Обновил и добавил пример с проблемой.